# water cooler fan in my computer room

Tags: physical-environment

Is using water cooler fan in my computer room HARMFUL for the internal parts of the computer system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An evaporative cooler can be if it causes the humidity to rise too high (above 60% or so). If humidity is not too low in the server room (20% will cause static generation to increase) then you should consider using refrigerative cooling instead.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, read up [Is humidity a problem for PC's?](http://www.pcuser.com.au/pcuser/hs2.nsf/lookup+1/D8CC2562ECD32A92CA256F59007F97E7)
Remember, if you start controlling humidity -- very low humidity can cause static-charge related problems [too](http://www.pcguide.com/care/care/gen/envHumidity-c.html). And a [fluctuating humidity](http://weatherwing.com/Home-Humidity.html) might lead to condensation related problems.